# Want to develop spring application with UDP server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, udp, listener

I want to develop spring standalone application with UDP server which will work live a
listener, will work to listen messages from other devices.
So suggest me which part of spring/spring boot is useful for here?

Also I'm very new to spring.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score -3):

A good solution would be the usage of `spring integration`. 
It is an abstraction that follows `Enterprise Integration Patterns`, basically, you use messages abstraction and therefore you can treat data from various sources in the same way. Docs are available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html).